# objectsPassingTest: Vs filteredSetUsingPredicate:?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, foundation, nsset

I want to get an `AccountUser`'s `linkedAccount` of type `LinkedAccountFacebook`, where `AccountUser` has many `LinkedAccount`'s (in Core Data).

Which is better to use?

1. `objectsWithOptions:passingTest:`

   ```
   NSSet *facebookLinkedAccounts =
   [activeAccountUser.linkedAccounts objectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
       if ([(LinkedAccount *)obj hasType:LinkedAccountTypeFacebook]) {
           *stop = YES;
           return YES;
       } else {
           return NO;
       }
   }];
   ```
2. `filteredSetUsingPredicate:`

   ```
   NSSet *facebookLinkedAccounts =
   [activeAccountUser.linkedAccounts filteredSetUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %i", LinkedAccountTypeFacebook]];
   ```
3. Perform a fetch request via the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling activeAccountUser.linkedAccounts will fetch them all from core data (if they are a fault), assuming you have the relationship set up.

Is `linkedAccounts' a fault? i.e Is it already in memory? If so, I'd use (2.). If the data is still in your backing store id execute the fetch request with the predicate filtering to the linked account type you needed so (3.)

Or if you are planning on fetching all the other types anyway, maybe it would be better to fetch them all up front.

Try them both side by side and run the Instruments time profiler on them.